# Splitting YYYYMMDD format date into months?

Tags: python-3.x, date-format, split

I have a file with about 200 lines of dates. Each of the dates is in YYYYMMDD format. How can I separate out each months data so I can get the averages of each month?

This is the best I've been able to figure out how to do it

```
Dates = line.split()
Year= Dates[0][0:4]
Month = Dates[0][4:6]
Date = Dates [0][6:8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file looks similar to this:

```
20131001 20131005 20130101 20130202
20130109 20130702 20130503 20130701
20130712 20130401 20131101 20131123
```

Here is what I would do to get a list of all the months in the file:

```
with open('dates.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

months = [date[4:6] for line in lines for date in line.split()]

print(months)
```

To deal with the dates as actual datetime objects, use the `datetime.strptime` method to convert the date strings to datetime objects.